# Xamarin Getting GPS location data in the background when the app is closed

Tags: android, service, xamarin, background, gps

i am building an android app which retrieves location data from the device when its running as background service and when its connected to the server it would send the gps data to the server. The functionality of the app must not stop when the app is closed. Can you guys guide me through the process, or provide me some reference or sample code to do this. I am really struggling to make the app run in the background when its closed.

-Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is a sample app on the Xamarin documentation site that appears to match [1]

However, I would ask to clarify if, when you say "when the app is closed" are you referring to it being backgrounded, or the application being completely closed from the application manager? Either way, background services may be helpful as well [2]

Thanks!

[1]
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/backgrounding/part_3_android_backgrounding_walkthrough/

[2]
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/backgrounding/part_2_android_services/

Comment: The app won't be closed completely it would run in the background.

Comment: In that case, the first sample link under item 1 should cover the proper technique.

Comment: I have tried that sample solution, it stops getting GPS location when i close the app but the app is running in background.